# Django 404 - URLs.py

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I think my URLs.py files are the only ones that matter but if you need more just let me know. When I go to localhost:8000/notendur/ I get a 404 error. It worked before, but, unfortunately, I can't remember what I of this I have changed. Error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/notendur/

Using the URLconf defined in tbg.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^$ ^notendur/$
    ^$ ^reikniverk/$
    ^notendur/
    ^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

/ PROJECT:

```
tbg/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tbg.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    #url(r'^notendur/$', 'notendur.views.Info_view', name='Info_view'),
    #url(r'^reikniverk/$', 'notendur.views.Reikniverk_view'),
    url(r'^$', include('notendur.urls')),
    url(r'^notendur/', include('notendur.urls')),
    #url(r'^reikniverk/', include('reikniverk.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

/ APPLICATION:

```
notendur/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from notendur.models import *
from django.views.generic import ListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^notendur/$', ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Information.objects.all(),
    template_name="notendur.html")),
    url(r'^reikniverk/$', 'notendur.views.Reikniverk_view'),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in`notendur/urls.py`

it should be

```
 url(r'^$', ..... instead of url(r'notendusr/^$'
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is that though? Shouldn't the regx match the url?

Comment: @user1614466 that means ..look first urldispatcher matches notendur/ in ur main url.py next it enters into application url. but in application url u have given again natendusr/ this mean localhost/notendusr/notendusr/ but our requirement is localhost/notendusr/ so remove the second notendusr/ in application url.hope u understand